# Visualizing Residuals and Squared Residuals in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a plot based on the diamonds data-set with a regression line and 10 cases. I want to add a residual (a vertical line going from observed `price` to its predicted value, the regression line, in red) specificly for one case (case 3, with the second highest value for `price`). In a second plot I want to add a red square with side equal to its residual (with the residual on the right side so the square doesn't overlap with the regression line) just to visualize the residuals and the squared residuals (I always do them in red). The code I have so far is shown below. Does someone know how to create these?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
data(diamonds)
set.seed(123)
small_n = sample_n(diamonds, 10, replace = TRUE)
small_n = select(small_n, price, carat)

p = ggplot(small_n, aes(x = carat, y = price))
p = p +
geom_point() +
ggtitle("Price by Carat") +
geom_hline(yintercept = mean(small_n$price),
         linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_vline(xintercept= mean(small_n$carat),
         linetype = "dashed") +
    geom_smooth(method=lm,   # Add linear regression lines
          se=FALSE, color = "black", size = .2) +
    coord_cartesian(xlim = c(0, 3), ylim = c(0, 13000))

p
```

Comment: can you show an example of your desired second plot?

Comment: so it's just a red square attached to the vertical residual going from 'price' observed to 'price' predicted. Or can i upload a hand made drawing?

Comment: Based on `fit <- lm(price~carat, small_n);ggplot(small_n, aes(x = carat, y = price)) + geom_point() + geom_abline(intercept = coef(fit)[1], slope = coef(fit)[2]) -> p`, maybe `p + geom_segment(data = cbind(small_n[3,], pred=predict(fit, small_n[3,])), aes(yend = pred, xend = carat), color = "red")` and `p + geom_rect(data = cbind(small_n[3,], size=abs(predict(fit, small_n[3,])-small_n$price[3])), aes(xmin = carat-size*diff(range(small_n$carat))/diff(range(small_n$price)), xmax=carat, ymin=price, ymax=price+size), fill="red") + theme(aspect=1)`.

Comment: With `fortify` you can acces the residuals: `modelo <- fortify(lm(small_n$price ~ small_n$carat)); p + geom_segment(aes(x = small_n$carat[3], y = small_n$price[3], xend = small_n$carat[3], yend = small_n$price[3] - modelo[3, ]$.resid, colour="red"))` and so on...

Comment: Great, the first plot works it's exactly what i need and i understand your code. The second one has a square, but it looks like a rectangle and the right side should be between the observation and the predicted value, now it is above the dot.

Comment: If you change `ymax=price+size` to `ymax=price-size`, the square goes down to the line.

Comment: it is a square going down now, the window needed to be rescaled!

Comment: Particularly for your first plot, you might find my post useful: https://drsimonj.svbtle.com/visualising-residuals